eBPF Verifier Errors: Invalid Access and Unbounded Memory Access in XDP Program
I am working on an eBPF XDP program that aggregates payloads from fragmented packets using a per-CPU array map. The program uses bpf_tail_call to handle packet fragments iteratively. However, I encounter verifier errors related to invalid and unbounded memory access when trying to print payload and aggregation results. Below is a simplified version of the code and the specific errors I encountered. I need help understanding and fixing these errors.

#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>

#define MAX_ARRAY_LEN 100

struct fragment_packet {
    __u32 payload[MAX_ARRAY_LEN];
};

struct {
    __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_PERCPU_ARRAY);
    __uint(key_size, sizeof(__u32));
    __uint(value_size, sizeof(__u32) * MAX_ARRAY_LEN);
    __uint(max_entries, 1);
} agg_result_map SEC(".maps");

struct {
    __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_PROG_ARRAY);
    __uint(key_size, sizeof(__u32));
    __uint(value_size, sizeof(__u32));
    __uint(max_entries, 1);
} tail_call_map SEC(".maps");

static __always_inline void aggregate_payload(__u32* agg_result, __u32* payload, __u32 start_index, int loop_len, void* data_end) {
    for (__u32 i = start_index; i < start_index + loop_len; i++) {
        if ((void*)(payload + i) >= data_end) return;
        if ((void*)(agg_result + i) >= data_end) return;
        bpf_printk("AGGREGATE: %u\n", payload[i]); // Error 1
        bpf_printk("AGGREGATE: %u\n", agg_result[i]); // Error 2
    }
}

SEC("xdp")
int aggr_handler_entry(struct xdp_md* ctx) {
    void* data_end = (void*)(long)ctx->data_end;
    void* data = (void*)(long)ctx->data;

    struct fragment_packet* pkt = data;
    if ((void*)(pkt + 1) > data_end) return XDP_PASS;

    __u32 key = 0;
    __u32* agg_result = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&agg_result_map, &key);
    if (!agg_result) return XDP_DROP;

    bpf_tail_call(ctx, &tail_call_map, 0);
    return XDP_DROP;
}

SEC("xdp")
int aggr_handler_tail(struct xdp_md* ctx) {
    void* data_end = (void*)(long)ctx->data_end;
    void* data = (void*)(long)ctx->data;

    struct fragment_packet* pkt = data;
    if ((void*)(pkt + 1) > data_end) return XDP_PASS;

    __u32 key = 0;
    __u32* agg_result = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&agg_result_map, &key);
    if (!agg_result) return XDP_DROP;

    __u32 start_index = 0; // example value
    __u32 loop_len = 50;    // example value

    aggregate_payload(agg_result, pkt->payload, start_index, loop_len, data_end);


    // go to tail cal again to handle next 50 elements, update start_index like start_index += loop_len then pass to next tail call by a map or meta_data
    return XDP_DROP;
}



Error 1: Invalid access to packet
(61) r3 = *(u32 *)(r2 +0)
invalid access to packet, off=74 size=4, R2(id=6,off=74,r=0)
R2 offset is outside of the packet


Error 2: Unbounded memory access
(61) r3 = *(u32 *)(r2 +0)
R2 unbounded memory access, make sure to bounds check any such access




The verifier complains about invalid access to the packet and unbounded memory access in the aggregate_payload function when trying to print the payload and aggregation results. I have checked the bounds of the payload and aggregation result arrays, but the verifier still flags these accesses as invalid.
How can I correctly handle these memory accesses and ensure the verifier passes? Any suggestions on modifying the code or adding necessary checks would be appreciated.

We will need the full verifier logs to solve the second error.

I think I found the issue for both errors (see below), but we would need the full verifier logs to be sure.

TL;DR. Your first error happens because your bound check doesn't include the access size. The second error likely happens because you're trying to compare a map value against the packet's end.

First Error: Explanation

(61) r3 = *(u32 *)(r2 +0)
invalid access to packet, off=74 size=4, R2(id=6,off=74,r=0)
R2 offset is outside of the packet


The verifier is telling you that you are trying to access the packet at offset 74 with an access size of 4 bytes; yet your packet is only known to have 74 bytes minimum.

First Error: Potential Solution
Changing the code to the following should fix the first error:
if ((void*)(payload + i + sizeof(__u32)) > data_end) return;
if ((void*)(agg_result + i + sizeof(__u32)) > data_end) return;

Note I also switched the >= to a >.

Second Error: Explanation

(61) r3 = *(u32 *)(r2 +0)
R2 unbounded memory access, make sure to bounds check any such access


In this case, assuming it's for the same C statements, the verifier seems to have no information on the checked bounds.
And indeed, you haven't really bound checked agg_result+i:

if ((void*)(agg_result + i) >= data_end) return;


Here, you are comparing agg_result+i to the packet's end. But agg_result+i isn't a packet pointer from the verifier's point of view. So this comparison won't count as a bound check.

Second Error: Potential Solution
Instead, you will need to compare it against the size of the value in the BPF map. And of course adjust for the first error as well. For example:
if ((void*)(agg_result + i + sizeof(__u32)) > sizeof(__u32) * MAX_ARRAY_LEN)
    return;

